# empty request when trying to edit top 200 row in SQL Server Managment Studio. How to fix it?

Tags: ssms

[[image: blank request]

[[image]

I tried to find this problem on YouTube, but no one had this, I tried to find it in the settings, but I did not find anything. I made the database through C# ef migrations. The database was created fine, but for some reason I can't edit it

Comment: 1. Don't use the "Edit top 200 rows" *'feature'*, it's buggy and quirky. 1b. Use a `UPDATE`/`INSERT`/`DELETE` statements instead. 2. What version of SSMS are you using? 3. What does Entity Framework and **MySQL** Management have to do with your question about SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: 1. Otherwise, I would not have been able to add data to this table if I had not used UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE
2. Well, I am using the latest verison 18.12.1.
3. I'm making a project in Angular so I use MySQL Management as a database to connect to WebAPI project . I hope I understood your question correctly

Comment: SSMS 18 only has limited support for SQL Server 2022; use SSMS 19 (Microsoft also recommends this). Also "MySQL Management" is going to have nothing to do with **SQL Server** (Management Studio); SQL Server and MySQL are *completely* different products.

Comment: Also, yes you would be able to alter the data without the edit feature; like I said use `UPDATE`/`INSERT`/`DELETE` statements instead.